# Find the limit of sequence $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2^{2}}+\frac{5}{2^{3}}+\cdots+\frac{2n-1}{2^{n}}$ without using of derivatives and etc.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I need to find limit of sequence
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2^{2}}+\frac{5}{2^{3}}+\cdots+\frac{2n-1}{2^{n}}\right)
$$
I tried to solve it and stopped here
$$
f(n+1) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2^{2}}+\frac{5}{2^{3}}+\cdots+\frac{2n-1}{2^{n}}+\frac{2n+1}{2^{n+1}}
$$
$$
2f(n+1) = 1+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{5}{2^{2}}+\cdots+\frac{2n-1}{2^{n-1}}+\frac{2n+1}{2^{n}}
$$
$$
2f(n+1) -f(n) = 1+ \left(1 + \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right) = 1 + g(n)
$$
I can find the limit of $g$, but what to do with the other parts?

Comment: Note that $\frac{2n}{2^{n}} = \frac{d}{dt} t^n |_{t=1/2}$ so you might be able to use power series since we have $\frac{2n-1}{2^n}=\frac{2n}{2^{n}} -\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: @Surb I need to calculate it without derivatives

Comment: Then you should clearly state it in your post.

Comment: @Surb changed the post

Comment: With derivatives, we have:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2n-1}{2^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}}= f'(1/2)-f(1/2)$$
with $f(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} t^n=\frac{1}{1-t}$.

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence#Infinite_series

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's assume that the limit exists. If we call the limit $s$ then

$s = \sum_1^{\infty}\frac{2n-1}{2^n}$

$\Rightarrow 2s = 1 + \sum_1^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{2^n} = 1 + \sum_1^{\infty}\frac{2n-1}{2^n} + \sum_1^{\infty}\frac{2}{2^n}$

$\Rightarrow 2s = 1 + s + \sum_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}$

$\Rightarrow 2s = 1 + s + 2$

$\Rightarrow s=3$

So *if* the limit exists then it must be 3.

Now you just have to prove that the limit exists i.e. the series converges.

Comment: To prove convergence: Using something similar to OP's notation $2f_{n+1} - f_n = 1 + g_n \le 3$. Thus by induction, if $f_n \le 3$ then $f_{n+1} \le 3$. $f_n$ is monotonically increasing and bounded above, so is convergent.

Answer (score 13):

Using the identity
$$
\frac{2k+1}{2^{k-1}}-\frac{2k+3}{2^k}=\frac{2k-1}{2^k}\tag1
$$
the sum can be written as a telescoping series
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2k-1}{2^k}
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{2k+1}{2^{k-1}}-\frac{2k+3}{2^k}\right)\\
&=3\tag2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 8):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2^{2}}+\frac{5}{2^{3}}+...+\frac{2n-1}{2^{n}}\right)=\sum _1^{\infty} \frac {2n-1}{2^n}=2\sum _1^{\infty} \frac {n}{2^n} -\sum _1^{\infty} \frac {1}{2^n}=2\sum _1^{\infty} \frac {n}{2^n} -1$$

Note that

\begin{align}
\sum _1^{\infty} \frac {n}{2^n}&=\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac14+\frac18+\frac18+\frac18+\cdots\right)\\&=\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac18 +\cdots\right) +\left(\frac14+\frac18+\frac1{16}+\cdots\right)+\left(\frac18+\frac1{16}+\frac1{32}+\cdots\right)+\cdots\\&=1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots=2
\end{align}

Thus  we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2^{2}}+\frac{5}{2^{3}}+\cdots+\frac{2n-1}{2^{n}}\right)= 3$$

Answer (score 2):

Use summation by parts. Given a sequence $f(n)$ define $(\Delta f)(n)=f(n+1)-f(n)$ and note that
$$
\sum_{n=a}^b(\Delta f)(n)=f(b+1)-f(a).
$$
Further given two sequences $f(n)$ and $g(n)$, note that
$$
(\Delta fg)(n)=f(n+1)\Delta g(n)+g(n)\Delta f(n)
$$
whence
$$
\sum_{n=a}^bg(n)\Delta f(n)=[f(b+1)g(b+1)-g(a)f(a)]-\sum_{n=a}^bf(n+1)\Delta g(n)\tag{1}
$$
Let $h(n)=-2/2^n$, and note that $\Delta h(n)=2^{-n}$. So by (1)
$$
\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{2n-1}{2^n}=[(2k+1)(-2^{-k})-1(-1)]+2\sum_{k=1}^n2^{-k}.\tag{2}
$$
Let $k\to \infty$ in (2) and use the formula for a geometric series to deduce that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n-1}{2^n}=1+2=3
$$